# Weight paint not acting the same way

Tags: weight-painting

Does anyone have any idea why are the cubes not attached to the rest of the mesh ? Both the mesh below them and the cubes weight paint are the same, but for some reason the cubes are moved in different way.

[image]

Comment: they must be part of another vertex group, which means that they will be influenced by another bone, you can select a vertex in Edit mode, open the N panel and take a look at the vertex weights

Comment: Hmm you were right, they were slightly affected by the other leg. I tried making the cubes be affected fully in both legs and then the cubes were acting as part of the rest of the character. Not quite sure why though, from what you were saying I should have done the opposite to fix the problem. Weight painting in blender is somewhat confusing for me. Sometimes vertices must be affected by more than 1 bone and other times they should be separate ... I should probably read more about all this...

Comment: select all these cubes in Edit mode and on the right of the Vertex Groups list click on the dropdown menu and choose Remove from All Groups, then weight paint these cubes with the good bone selected or assign them to the right vertex group

Comment: Oh that is a nice trick. It would save me lots of time rather than me having to hunt the cubes down in all nearby bones. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all these cubes in *Edit* mode and on the right of the *Vertex Groups* list click on the dropdown menu and choose *Remove from All Groups*, then weight paint these cubes with the good bone selected or assign them to the right vertex group.